# WebLogic service not reading Boot Identity file

Tags: windows-services, active-directory, weblogic, weblogic11g

I created a new ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator user for our WebLogic server and added the credentials to the boot.properties file under the `<Server>/security` folder. When I start the server with startWebLogic.cmd it boots it correctly with the specified user. However when I go through the example, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81b/adminguide/winservice.html, to create the service or try to modify the script that someone had created a few years ago, it does not boot the server with the correct user.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set DOMAIN_NAME=<domain_name>
set SERVER_NAME=<server_name>
set MAX_CONNECT_RETRIES=2
set HOST=localhost
set PORT=7011
set USERDOMAIN_HOME=F:\bea1032\user_projects\domains\<domain_name>

set WL_HOME=F:\bea1032\wlserver_10.3
call "%WL_HOME%\common\bin\commEnv.cmd"

:checkWLS
if exist "%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.jar" goto checkJava
goto finish

:checkJava
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto runWebLogic
goto finish

:runWebLogic
if not "%JAVA_VM%" == "" goto noResetJavaVM
if "%JAVA_VENDOR%" == "BEA" set JAVA_VM=-jrocket
if "%JAVA_VENDOR%" == "HP"  set JAVA_VM=-server
if "%JAVA_VENDOR%" == "Sun" set JAVA_VM=-server

:noResetJavaVM
if not "%MEM_ARGS%" == "" goto noResetMemArgs
set MEM_ARGS=-Xms32m -Xmx200m

:noResetMemArgs
set CLASSPATH=%WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH%;%CLASSPATH%

@echo off

if "%ADMIN_URL%" == "" goto runAdmin
@echo on
set CMDLINE="%JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% %JAVA_OPTIONS% -classpath \"%CLASSPATH%\" -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Dweblogic.management.server=\"%ADMIN_URL%\" -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=%PRODUCTION_MODE% -Djava.security.policy=\"%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.policy\" weblogic.Server"
goto finish

:runAdmin
@echo on
set CMDLINE="%JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% %JAVA_OPTIONS% -classpath \"%CLASSPATH%\" -Dweblogic.Name=%SERVER_NAME% -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=%PRODUCTION_MODE% -Djava.security.policy=\"%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.policy\" weblogic.Server"

:finish
if "%WL_USE_X86DLL%" == "true" set EXTRAPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\32;%WL_HOME%\server\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\32\oci920_8

if "%WL_USE_IA64DLL%" == "true" set EXTRAPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\64\;%WL_HOME%\server\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\64\oci920_8

if "%WL_USE_AMD64DLL%" == "true" set EXTRAPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\x64\;%WL_HOME%\server\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8

"%WL_HOME%\server\bin\beasvc" -install -svcname:"beasvc %DOMAIN_NAME%_%SERVER_NAME%" -javahome:"%JAVA_HOME%" -execdir:"%USERDOMAIN_HOME%" -maxconnectretries:"%MAX_CONNECT_RETRIES%" -host:"%HOST%" -port:"%PORT%" -extrapath:"%EXTRAPATH%" -cmdline:%CMDLINE%

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Have you tried forcing it to use the user/pass you want with `WLS_USER` and `WLS_PW` or setting those directly as `-user:` and `-password:` in your beasvc call?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. I actually was able to get it to work by making the service run with that user as well instead of LOCAL SYSTEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually was able to get it to work by making the service run with that user as well instead of LOCAL SYSTEM.